# Atlassian Stash and Dploy

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I'm having a problem and I just cannot figure it out, been researching for days on end and trying MANY combinations and methods, but cannot seem to figure this one out.

I use Atlassian Stash as a self-hosted git cental repo.
https://www.atlassian.com/software/stash

I also use Dploy to deploy changes via FTP.
http://leanmeanfightingmachine.github.io/dploy/

Dploy creates its own post-commit hook in the .git/hooks/ folder as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
# DPLOY
message=$(git log -1 --all --pretty=%B)
tag="#dploy"
if [[ "$message" = *"$tag"* ]]; then
    servers=${tag}${message#*${tag}}
    noTag=${servers//#/""}
    eval $noTag
fi
```

When I execute dploy explicitly from cli, it runs successfully and finishes. All works well. Command below:

```
dploy dev
```

However, when I commit like this:

```
commit -m "#dploy dev - Initial commit"
```

It gets stuck (wont accept any keyboard input) and I have to Ctrl+C to get out of it.

```
[ Wed Jun 11 2014  11:58:29  macbook as chris @ ami] git commit -m     "#dploy dev"
Connecting to dev...
Checking revisions...
Checking diffs between [4361308e87183d8dfaf556da3182dd1095f58486] >     [dd70f1cf70957e9e672cd371499fb4183a9d8b3b]
Files that will be uploaded:
[ ? ] .rev > public_html/ami/.rev
[ ? ] test.txt > public_html/ami/test.txt
[ ? ] .rev > public_html/ami/.rev
– Are you sure you want to upload those files? (Y/n)
```

Its probably a very specific issue - had anyone experienced this or figured out a solution?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix as provided by the dev:

https://github.com/LeanMeanFightingMachine/dploy/issues/54